# returning the values to my the method calling it

Tags: java, return

I have the following method

```
private void gettablewidths() {
   JTableHeader th = tableR.getTableHeader();
   TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();
   for(int x = 0, y = tcm.getColumnCount(); x < y; x++)
       {
        TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(x);
        double header = (double) tc.getHeaderValue();
        System.out.println("Column name = "+tc.getHeaderValue()+", width = "+tc.getWidth());
        return  ;
    }
 }
```

It is called by

```
gettablewidths();
```

from within another method (other method)

How do i go about returning all the column widths of my table so that i can use them in my other method?

The overall point is to get the values of the widths of the columns
A refresh then occurs of the table model.
The get value widths are applied to the table so that the user doesn't have to resize the columns again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  tc.getWidth()  //returns an int
```

Create an arraylist of integers outside of your loop and add the results of tc.getWidth()) to your arraylist inside your loop:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int x = 0, y = tcm.getColumnCount(); x < y; x++)
    {
        tc = tcm.getColumn(x);
        list.add(tc.getWidth());
    }
```

Part2 - 
  Returning your arraylist in another method

Change your method return type so you return your arraylist:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> gettablewidths(){

// logic.....
return ArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the width of the columns is an `int` value. In the class where you are calling `getTableWidths();` you should set an integer equal to it, such as `int width = getTableWidths();`
Your method should look something like this. However, I was confused why you were calling `return ;` inside the loop, so I commented it out.

### getTableWidths()

```
private int getTableWidths() 
{
    int totalWidth = 0; // This is what you'll return as the width
    JTableHeader th = tableR.getTableHeader();
    TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();
    for(int x = 0, y = tcm.getColumnCount(); x < y; x++)
    {
        TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(x);
        double header = (double) tc.getHeaderValue();
        System.out.println("Column name = " + tc.getHeaderValue() + ", width = " + tc.getWidth());
        // return  ;
        totalWidth += tc.getWidth();
    }
    return totalWidth;
}
```

To change it to return a `double`, just set all the `int` definitions in it (besides in the `for` loop) to `double`.

This was just for the total width value, I didn't realize you wanted every single width of the table. Since you already know how many columns the table has, you could use an array if you wanted.

### getTableWidths() `// return integer array`

```
private int[] getTableWidths() 
    {
        int[] widths; // This is what you'll return as the width
        JTableHeader th = tableR.getTableHeader();
        TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();
        widths = new int[tcm.getColumnCount()];
        for(int x = 0, y = tcm.getColumnCount(); x < y; x++)
        {
            TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(x);
            double header = (double) tc.getHeaderValue();
            System.out.println("Column name = " + tc.getHeaderValue() + ", width = " + tc.getWidth());
            // return  ;
            widths[x] = tc.getWidth();
        }
        return widths;
    }
```

Comment: Oh if he meant all the table widths than arggggg my bad

Comment: @ Riley Carney will this work since i think your combines the widths and returns that to the other method..

Comment: The first does, the second one where I labeled `// return integer array` returns an array of integers, or all the widths that the table was made out of.

Answer (score -1):

Change the return type from void to a type you want to return the weight as.

In the new method, make its parameter the data type returned by gettablewidths();